# Where to find textbook with Toda Yamamoto causality test example?

Tags: time-series, references, causality, vector-autoregression, granger-causality

I'm trying to create a Toda Yamamoto analysis on a VAR system, for Granger causality test, so far i only find a book where is mentioned:

- Levendis, J. D. (2018). Time Series Econometrics: Learning Through Replication Springer -Texts in Business and Economics, ISSN 2192-4333. DOI, 10, 978-3.

But there is no numerical example, i will like to test this method with a full documented example. Is there any textbook where i can find it? i look this for teaching and research.

So far, I found an example from this [blog](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/264928_22ecfa42ed0d4b6a814a6a76a96deaa5.html) but no textbook.

Thanks for reading my question.

PD: Sorry for my English

Comment: See https://davegiles.blogspot.com/2011/04/testing-for-granger-causality.html and https://davegiles.blogspot.com/2014/05/questions-about-granger-causality.html and perhaps some other posts from the same blog. I think they are as good as it gets.